# How to filter items in bulks?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb

I'm implementing a Job with Spring Batch, and my simple scenario is:

1. read items from a file
2. process each item
3. write item chunks to a database

The problem is that I want to filter out the items that are already present in the database.

My first try was to query the database in step two for the current item and, if already present, return null from the ItemProcessor so that the item is filtered out.
This was unnecessary slow because is needed one query for each processed item.

So my second try was to override the doWrite method in the ItemWriter to make a single query for the whole chunk and write only the items without a match from the query.
Even if there was a neat increase in performance this doesn't look good to me (in this way Spring Batch cannot see what I'm actually writing to the database, indeed write and filter counters from the StepContext have wrong values).

What is the correct way to implement this processing logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be calling `skip` (as in `skip the items that are already present in the database`) is actually filtering items and not skipping them according to Spring Batch's terminology. The skip feature in Spring Batch is for invalid items (ie those that cause an exception to be thrown while reading, processing or writing them).

A common technique that could work well in your use case is to make the item writer idempotent, by doing a "save or update" operation. This removes the need to check if an item is present or not. Moreover, this is useful in case of failure as you can just re-run the failed job without having to store any progress state.

Comment: all right, this seems the right way to go. So my second attempt was near, instead of filtering out the items I just need to implement the update logic in the doWrite method (I'm using a MongoItemWriter). thank you for the reply

Comment: Great. Since your are using the `MongoItemWriter`, it already does an `upsert` operation (and if you are using Spring Batch 4.3, you would benefit from this improvement: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3713).

Comment: I see, but probably I need to implement a custom logic anyway since the items have not the id property set in place of writing. Also I would like to update only not null values

Answer (score 0):

Your second way of doing a single select at the start of the ItemWriter to find existing items is ok, even if it means you won't see correct stats that indicate exactly how many rows were written to the database and how many were ignored because they already exist.

If you have the option, you could create another table in the same schema as the table you're writing to, you can then load all rows from the file into that other table in a stage of the spring batch job, then in the next stage you query from that table and select only the rows that don't exist in the destination table.